# Sed: replacing digits

Tags: scripting, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to write some install scripts for when I install/upgrade Ubuntu. I'm having trouble with fixing `logrotate.d`:

```
/var/log/ufw.log
{
rotate 7
weekly
missingok
notifempty
compress
delaycompress
sharedscripts
postrotate
    reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
endscript
}
```

I want to change `rotate nnn` to `rotate 99`. It must work for nnn to be any number of digits (normally 1 or 2), yet not affect the `postrotate` line.

I've tried these two but neither does what I need (and I tested with nnn being 1,2 or 3 digits).

```
sudo sed  's/rotate[0-9]*/rotate 99/' /etc/logrotate.d/ufw
sudo sed  's/^rotate[0-9]/rotate 99/' /etc/logrotate.d/ufw
```

Answer (score 14):

`sed 's/rotate [0-9]\+/rotate 99/'`

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 5):

`rotate[0-9]*` replaces `rotate` followed by zero or more digits, which matches the end of `postrotate`. `rotate[0-9]` replaces only one digit. Furthermore you're missing the space after `rotate`. I think this does what you want; it also handles indented lines:

```
sudo sed 's/^\( *rotate *\)[0-9][0-9]*/\1 99/' /etc/logrotate.d/ufw
```

Add the `-i` option to `sed` if you want to change the file in place.